# Copy and Rename files from one location to another using an input file

Tags: bash, batch-rename

I need to Copy some files from one location with subfolders to another but at the same time I do need to rename them. I have the list that has the specific files with their location, where they should copied to and, the new file name. I am not fussy about the language and I can modify the input file as per the needs.

I have seen multiple questions on that but none of them is actually using a input file to achieve that.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Did you try using `while read` loop to read the file?

Comment: `while read source target_dir target_name; do mv "$source" "$target_dir/$target_name"; done < file_with_the_3_infos_per_line` or something like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question for anybody who needs.

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
while IFS=" " read -r Source Dest OldName NewName
do
FullName="${Dest}""${NewName}"
cd "$Source"
mkdir -p "$Dest"
cp "$OldName" "$FullName"
done < "input.txt"
```